# Index was outside bounds of array

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the secure delete extension but i get Index was outside bounds of array when i execute it.I have already added the ddl file as a reference

http://microsoftwinanyhelper.codeplex.com/documentation

```
    using Microsoft.WinAny.IO;
   //showing only relevant part here 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\test.jpg");
                fi.Delete(OverwriteAlgorithm.DoD_7);
            }
```

Here are more details about the error.
**Edit 1** I pasted the wrong error guys .It was happening because i clicked on delete a second time to get the error message a second time and thus came the file in use issue

Here is the correct one

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Microsoft.WinAny.Helper.dll

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.



See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Microsoft.WinAny.IO.SecureDeleteExtensions.OverwriteFile_DoD_7(FileInfo file)
   at Microsoft.WinAny.IO.SecureDeleteExtensions.Delete(FileInfo file, OverwriteAlgorithm overwriteAlgorithm)
   at UltimateDelete.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Gr33k\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UltimateDelete\UltimateDelete\Form1.cs:line 43
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
UltimateDelete
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Gr33k/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202013/Projects/UltimateDelete/UltimateDelete/bin/Debug/UltimateDelete.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34251 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.WinAny.Helper
    Assembly Version: 1.0.1.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Gr33k/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202013/Projects/UltimateDelete/UltimateDelete/bin/Debug/Microsoft.WinAny.Helper.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: It seems like the exception message says it pretty well.

Comment: The exception says the file is in use, what makes you think there is an index out of bounds issue? `System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\test.jpg' because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\test.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Your exception message says that the file cannot be deleted because it is in use--it has NOTHING to do with "Index outside bounds of array".

Comment: @EdT I updated the question

Comment: Post the stack trace, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception says something else:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\test.jpg' because it is being used by another process.
```

So you should address that. It's pretty much self explanatory.

EDIT (after the question getting corrected): Looks like the exception is occurring in the referenced assembly. Might be a bug.

EDIT: The exception seems to be thrown in code beyond your reach. You might as well report it as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

That 3rd party library has a bug in it, I took a look at the source to find it for you:

```
byte[] pattern = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xFF, 0x72, 0x96, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x72 };

...

for (int pass = 1; pass <= 7; ++pass)
{
    ... = pattern[pass];
    ...
}
```

The `for` loop interates from 1 to 7, instead of 0 to 6, so it will always throw this error.  As others have suggested, you should report it as a bug to the library creator.

As an aside, that library does not properly handle cleanup if any exception gets raised while doing it's file operations so it can leave undisposed resources laying around.